# Single domain with multiple server names

Tags: domain, asp.net, domain-name, godaddy

I have a complex case below and I am not an expert with domains at all:
I have a domain in godaddy and it points to Wix website "mydomain.com" also I have a host in "asp.net" and need to use same domain "mydomain.com".

1. Is it possible to point Wix to "Mydomian.com" and my hosting to "Mydomian.com/admin"?
2. if we can't do the point #1 is it possible to make a subdomain, Wix use "mydomain.com" and my hosting use "admin.mydomain.com"

In all cases I want to make the domain and subdomains in SSL mode

Answer (score 0):

You Can Act in way 2 Easy. But you Should talk to your ASP host to add a subdomain `admin.mydomain.com` into your host!
Then you can use SSL too!
But for the first Way you should do `redirects` and in that case, you must use another domain to provide your ASP hosting.